# Does the asymptotic complexity of a multiplication algorithm only rely on the larger of the two operands?

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity, big-o, multiplication, asymptotic-complexity

I'm taking an algorithms class and I repeatedly have trouble when I'm asked to analyze the runtime of code when there is a line with multiplication or division. How can I find big-theta of multiplying an n digit number with an m digit number (where n>m)? Is it the same as multiplying two n digit numbers?

For example, right now I'm attempting to analyze the following line of code:

```
return n*count/100
```

where count is at most 100. Is the asymptotic complexity of this any different from n*n/100? or n*n/n?

Comment: In an algorithmic class, you usually assume all arithmetic operations to be constant and focus on the complexity of the algorithm using them.

Comment: The course I'm in seems to stress making sure the analysis remains true for extremely large inputs, so multiplication cannot be constant.

Answer (score 0):

You can always look up here [Computational complexity of mathematical operations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computational_complexity_of_mathematical_operations).

In your complexity of `n*count/100` is O(length(n)) as 100 is a constant and length(count) is at most 3.

In general multiplication of two numbers n and m digits length, takes O(nm), the same time required for division. Here i assume we are talking about long division. There are many sophisticated algorithms which will beat this complexity.

To make things clearer i will provide an example. Suppose you have three numbers:

- A - n digits length
- B - m digits length
- C - p digits length

Find complexity of the following formula:

`A * B / C`

**Multiply first.** Complexity of `A * B` it is `O(nm)` and as result we have number  D, which is n+m digits length. Now consider `D / C`, here complexity is `O((n+m)p)`, where overall complexity is sum of the two `O(nm + (n+m)p) = O(m(n+p) + np)`.

**Divide first.** So, we divide `B / C`, complexity is `O(mp)` and we have m digits number E. Now we calculate `A * E`, here complexity is `O(nm)`. Again overall complexity is `O(mp + nm) = O(m(n+p))`.

From the analysis you can see that it is beneficial to divide first. Of course in real life situation you would account for numerical stability as well.

Answer (score 0):

From [Modern Computer Arithmetic](https://members.loria.fr/PZimmermann/mca/pub226.html):

Assume the larger operand has size
m, and the smaller has size n ≤ m, and denote by M(m,n) the corresponding
multiplication cost.

When m is an exact multiple of n, say m = kn, a trivial strategy is to cut the
larger operand into k pieces, giving `M(kn,n) = kM(n) + O(kn)`.

Suppose m ≥ n and n is large. To use an evaluation-interpolation scheme,
we need to evaluate the product at m + n points, whereas balanced k by k
multiplication needs 2k points. Taking k ≈ (m+n)/2, we see that `M(m,n) ≤ M((m + n)/2)(1 + o(1))` as n → ∞. On the other hand, from the discussion
above, we have `M(m,n) ≤ ⌈m/n⌉M(n)(1 + o(1))`.